# Combining a list of objects with periods into unique lists

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, tree

I have a list of Objects. Each object is unique by ID combined with a time period -- FromDate and ToDate.

The list could look like this(in real life there are more attributes):

**ID; FromDate; ToDate**
1; 2000-1-1; 2019-12-31
2; 2000-1-1; 2019-12-31
3; 2000-1-1; 2009-12-31
3; 2010-1-1; 2019-12-31
4; 2000-1-1; 2019-12-31
5; 2000-1-1; 2014-12-31
5; 2015-1-1; 2019-12-31

**Note:**

- Both objects id=3 and id=5 have two incarnations (periods)
- It can be assumed that there are no gaps in the period for an id.
- The list is always ordered as shown

What I want is several lists of objects each with a unique period containing only one of each id:

***LIST1:***
Period=2000-1-1 to 2009-12-31
ListOfObjects: 1;2;3(First period);4;5(First period)

***LIST2:***
Period=2010-1-1 to 2014-12-31
ListOfObjects: 1;2;3(Second period);4;5(First period)

***LIST3:***
Period=2015-1-1 to 2019-12-31
ListOfObjects: 1;2;3(Second period);4;5(Second period)

I am pretty sure that some recursive calculating is required here, but other than that, I'm all question marks. Please help!!! Write me, if further information is needed.

Regards, 
Morten :o)

Comment: you periods for the results are all the same.  Is this correct?

Comment: No, sorry. The mistake is corrected. Thanks for the heads up :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by your input -- and thanks for that -- I came up with a solution. I create a tree of all possible combinations. The root of the tree is the first item in the list of objects. My tree handler class calls itself recursively to loop trough the objects. At the leaf node, I check for a intersection of periods of all the nodes in the path. If there is an intersecting period, I have a valid combination, and the treehandler passes that on throug a delegate. If the path does not have an intersecting period, it cannot be used. I have excluded secondary classes, but i can insert them, if you request it:

```
internal delegate void PathDelivery(JPTreeNode treeNode, Period periodInCommon); //Deliver a path through this delegate


internal class TreeHandler //The main class
{
    private readonly PathDelivery _pathDelivery;

    // Construct with 
    public TreeHandler(PathDelivery pathDelivery)
    {
        _pathDelivery = pathDelivery; 
    }

    public void HandleNode(IList<SourceRow> jpSource, int level,JPTreeNode parentNode, Period intersectingPeriod)
    {
        int sequenceId = level + 1;

        IList<SourceRow> children = new List<SourceRow>(System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(jpSource, S => S.Id == sequenceId));
        if (children.Count == 0) //The last leaf level... return the path throug PathDelivery delegate if valid dates
        {
            if (intersectingPeriod!= null)
                _pathDelivery(parentNode, intersectingPeriod); //Only deliver this path if all nodes in path has an intersecting period
        }
        else //This node has children to add
        {
            foreach (SourceRow child in children) //Loop and create children 
            {
                Stop stop = new Stop(child.Id, child.Period, child.Description); //Value object for child node

                //Re-calculate the valid period (intersect) for the tree path 
                Period newIntersect = Period.Intersect(stop.Period, intersectingPeriod); 

                JPTreeNode childNode = new JPTreeNode(parentNode, stop); //Create the child node 

                if (parentNode!= null) //If not at root level, add child node to parent node
                    parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(childNode);

                // Recursive call, handle possible grandchildren (children of this childNode) or finish path
                HandleNode(jpSource, sequenceId, childNode, newIntersect); 
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Below is a unit test fixture that demonstrates the use:

```
[TestFixture]
public sealed class TestRecursiveDataHandling
{
    private IList<Path> _pathList;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _pathList = new List<Path>();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _pathList = null; 
    }

    [Test]
    public void CreateLists()
    {
        //Create the data source 
        IList<SourceRow> jpSource = new List<SourceRow>();
        jpSource.Add(new SourceRow("1", 1, new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), new DateTime(2009, 12, 31)));
        jpSource.Add(new SourceRow("2A", 2, new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), new DateTime(2004, 12, 31)));
        jpSource.Add(new SourceRow("2B", 2, new DateTime(2005, 1, 1), new DateTime(2009, 12, 31)));
        jpSource.Add(new SourceRow("3", 3, new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), new DateTime(2009, 12, 31)));
        jpSource.Add(new SourceRow("4A", 4, new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), new DateTime(2008, 12, 31)));
        jpSource.Add(new SourceRow("4B", 4, new DateTime(2009, 1, 1), new DateTime(2009, 12, 31)));


        //Instantiate handler
        TreeHandler handler = new TreeHandler(CreatePathFromButtonNode);

        //Handle root node, and recurse 
        handler.HandleNode(jpSource, 0, null, Period.Infinite);


        //DISPLAY TREE PATHS IN CONSOLE 
        DisplayResultInConsole();

        //A simple assertion. Expect that 3 paths were created.
        Assert.That(_pathList.Count, Is.EqualTo(3));


    }

    private void DisplayResultInConsole()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _pathList.Count;  i++ )
        {
            IList<Stop> jpList = _pathList[i].Stops;
            string stopList = string.Empty; 
            foreach (Stop stop in jpList)
            {
                stopList = stopList + stop.ID + ";" + stop.Description + ";"+ stop.Period + " \n";
            }

            string p = "List " + i + ">> Period " + _pathList[i].Period;

            Console.WriteLine("List " + i + ">> Period " +  p);
            Console.WriteLine("Stops: ");
            Console.WriteLine(stopList);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }



    //Method for receiving paths from leaf nodes. Passed as delegate to TreeHandler
    private void CreatePathFromButtonNode(JPTreeNode treeNode, Period periodInCommon)
    {
        IList<Stop> stopList = new List<Stop>();
        JPTreeNode currentNode = treeNode; 
        while (currentNode!= null)
        {
            stopList.Add(currentNode.NodeValue);
            currentNode = currentNode.ParentNode; 
        }

         _pathList.Add(new Path(periodInCommon, stopList));
    }





}
```

This test generates the following output to Console. Note that the path (combination) 4B;3;2A;1 has not been returned. This is because the periods of 2A and 4B does not intersect:

List 0>> Period List 0>> Period From: 1/1/2000 To: 12/31/2004
Stops:
4;4A;From: 1/1/2000 To: 12/31/2008
3;3;From: 1/1/2000 To: 12/31/2009
2;2A;From: 1/1/2000 To: 12/31/2004
1;1;From: 1/1/2000 To: 12/31/2009

List 1>> Period List 1>> Period From: 1/1/2005 To: 12/31/2008
Stops:
4;4A;From: 1/1/2000 To: 12/31/2008
3;3;From: 1/1/2000 To: 12/31/2009
2;2B;From: 1/1/2005 To: 12/31/2009
1;1;From: 1/1/2000 To: 12/31/2009

List 2>> Period List 2>> Period From: 1/1/2009 To: 12/31/2009 
Stops:
4;4B;From: 1/1/2009 To: 12/31/2009
3;3;From: 1/1/2000 To: 12/31/2009
2;2B;From: 1/1/2005 To: 12/31/2009
1;1;From: 1/1/2000 To: 12/31/2009

Answer (score 3):

I'd first create your unique ranges of dates from the from dates and to dates by ordering the unique from/to dates in increasing order.  As the dates are unbroken this should be a contiguous list.

Then I would select each 'pair' of consecutive dates in the list based on the order of the list and use that as a new period.  So the first period would be date 0 and date 1, the second period would be date 2 and 3, then date 4 and 5 etc etc  Then I would add each item which intersects with that range of dates to the list of objects within the range.

so based on your data list would be:

2000-1-1
2009-12-31
2010-1-1
2014-12-31
2015-1-1
2019-12-31

then your groups would be:

2000-1-1 to 2009-12-31 objects 1,2,3(first),4,5(first)
2010-1-1 to 2014-12-31 objects 1,2,3(second),4,5(first)
2015-1-1 to 2019-12-31 objects 1,2,3(second),4,5(second)

This is assuming that your original required results was not correct.

**EDIT**

The original required results were not correct, but now align with what this approach should achieve

Comment: Yes, that would do the trick. But being a spoiled brat, I was kind of hoping for a code example ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the group by linq commands:

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1

Update:
Time runs out, I post an unfinished result, maybe it helps. Hopefully I can continue in a few hours.
This returns two collections containing 1,2,3(first),4,5(first) and 1,2,3(second),4,5(second).

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var xs = new List<X>
                     {
                         new X("1; 2000-1-1; 2019-12-31"),
                         new X("2; 2000-1-1; 2019-12-31"),
                         new X("3; 2000-1-1; 2009-12-31"),
                         new X("3; 2010-1-1; 2019-12-31"),
                         new X("4; 2000-1-1; 2019-12-31"),
                         new X("5; 2000-1-1; 2014-12-31"),
                         new X("5; 2015-1-1; 2019-12-31")
                     };

        var groupedById = (from x in xs
                          group x by x.Id into ids
                          select ids);

        var maxOccurances = groupedById
            .Max(x => x.Count());

        var result = new List<List<X>>();

        for (var i = 0; i < maxOccurances; i++)
        {
            var list = groupedById.Select(idGroup => idGroup.Count() < i
                                                         ? idGroup.ElementAt(i)
                                                         : idGroup.Last())
                .ToList();
            result.Add(list);
        }
    }

    public class X
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }

        public X(string input)
        {
            var splitted = input.Split(';');
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[0]);
            DateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(splitted[1]);
            DateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(splitted[2]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: will this code actually solve the problem?  If not then some indication of the code that will actually be useful in the context of the OP's question would probably be more useful.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to my "time slizing" problem. Enlighten me, please ;o)

Comment: Ops, i missunderstood the question. Updated my post to a partial result.

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx) allows you to handle multiple time periods.

First let's define a custom time range including your id:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class IdTimeRange : TimeRange
{

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  public IdTimeRange( int id, DateTime start, DateTime end ) :
    base( start, end )
  {
    Id = id;
  } // IdTimeRange    

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  public int Id { get; private set; }

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  public override string ToString()
  {
    return Id + ": " + base.ToString();
  } // ToString

} // IdTimeRange
```

Now you can use a **TimePeriodCollection** in combination with a **TimeLine** to find all intersecting periods:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void TimeLinePeriodsSample()
{
  TimePeriodCollection periods = new TimePeriodCollection();
  periods.Add( new IdTimeRange( 1, new DateTime( 2000, 1, 1 ), new DateTime( 2019, 12, 31 ) ) );
  periods.Add( new IdTimeRange( 2, new DateTime( 2000, 1, 1 ), new DateTime( 2019, 12, 31 ) ) );
  periods.Add( new IdTimeRange( 3, new DateTime( 2000, 1, 1 ), new DateTime( 2009, 12, 31 ) ) );
  periods.Add( new IdTimeRange( 3, new DateTime( 2010, 1, 1 ), new DateTime( 2019, 12, 31 ) ) );
  periods.Add( new IdTimeRange( 4, new DateTime( 2000, 1, 1 ), new DateTime( 2019, 12, 31 ) ) );
  periods.Add( new IdTimeRange( 5, new DateTime( 2000, 1, 1 ), new DateTime( 2014, 12, 31 ) ) );
  periods.Add( new IdTimeRange( 5, new DateTime( 2015, 1, 1 ), new DateTime( 2019, 12, 31 ) ) );
  foreach ( ITimePeriod period in periods )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Period: " + period );
  }

  // time line with all period start and end moments
  ITimeLineMomentCollection moments = new TimeLineMomentCollection();
  moments.AddAll( periods );
  DateTime start = periods.Start;
  foreach ( ITimeLineMoment moment in moments )
  {
    if ( moment.EndCount <= 0 ) // search the next period end
    {
      continue;
    }
    DateTime end = moment.Moment;
    TimeRange timeRange = new TimeRange( start, end );
    Console.WriteLine( "Period: {0}", timeRange );
    ITimePeriodCollection intersections = periods.IntersectionPeriods( timeRange );
    foreach ( ITimePeriod intersection in intersections )
    {
      Console.WriteLine( "  Intersection: {0}", intersection );
    }
    start = moment.Moment;
  }
} // TimeLinePeriodsSample
```

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting reading. However, your example assumes that the TimeRanges are known. In my problem the periods should be extracted from the periods in the PeriodCollection.

Comment: Do you mean the test periods?

Comment: Yes, you assume to know the dates of each TestPeriod. You also assume to know the number of TestPeriods. I receive my PeriodCollection from an database table, so I cannot make those assumtions.

Comment: OK. I'm using now the time line classes, to find the testing periods.

Comment: Thanks, I think we have arrived at the same finish line through different routes. See my answer for a description of my solution :-)